# Assigning a class to individual td elements in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a `table` to display different resort packages. The cells containing the name of package, number of nights included, and cost have to have their text centered. The cells containing the description need to have the text left justified.

In my CSS file, this is what I have regarding the table cells

```
td, th { border: 1px solid #3399CC; }
td { text-align: centered; }
.text td { text-align: left; }
```

When I try to apply to text class to a `td` element in my HTML file, it applies to to the entire table.

The line I edited looks like this

```
<td class="text" headers="description">...</td>
```

The other lines are simply

```
<td headers="name">...</td>
```

What do I need to be doing differently?

Comment: make id's instead of class

Comment: The assignment specifically asks us to configure a class named text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a misspelling. Text align should be set to `center` not `centered`.

Also, drop the `td` of `.text td { text-align: left; }` making it

`.text { text-align: left; }`

And you should be good.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to mark it as the answer for anyone else coming to this question.

Comment: Honestly have no idea how to do that. This is my first time using this site

Comment: No, problem. Welcome to stackoverflow! http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Specifically: `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.`

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple mistake about how CSS selectors work.

Each space means "child" if you will.

`.text td` means "Find an element with the class 'text' and apply X style to it's 'td' *child*"

If you want to apply a style to `td` with the class of `text`, you don't want any spaces; format it like this:

`td.text`, which would mean "Find a td element that has `text` for a class"

You can also chain multiple classes that way.

`td#unique.text.thingy` would mean "Find a td element with the id `unique`, the class `text` and the class `thingy`"

Thus giving

```
td, th {border: 1px solid #3399CC;}
td {text-align: centered;}
td.text {text-align: left}
```

Comment: I applied this change to my CSS file and got the same result. Do I need to change anything in my HTML file?

Comment: @BrennaMartin https://jsfiddle.net/7d1vzdg5/ Consider this jsfiddle. Mess around with it, see what makes your thing break and not mine. In fact, post your own JSfiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Why you are confusing OP, when it is clear OP just need to drop `td` from CSS? long and confusing explanation

Comment: @dippas Because it doesn't work and doesn't work *for a reason* that is vital to a basic understanding of CSS. This is *the* mistake that leads to so many others. I am perhaps confusing to an extent, but I give everything that she might need. Will she use it all? Hopefully. If not, I just gave her the correct CSS to use at the end of the question. OP can take as much value from my answer as she wants.

Comment: @BrennaMartin Note that if you proceed by just removing "td", *everything* that uses the `text` class will be affected - not just `td` elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create classes and apply feathers on the columns you want to apply to that desired style for example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title 1</th>
    <th>title 2</th>
    <th>title 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="text-justify">more info 1</td>
    <td class="text-left">$1000 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="text-justify">more info more 1</td>
    <td class="text-left">$ 100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="text-justify">more info 1</td>
    <td class="text-left">$ 100000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table { 
 border-spacing: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #3399CC;
  padding : 4px 8px;
}

.text-justify {
  text-align: justify
}
.text-left {
  text-align: left
}
```

see on link https://jsfiddle.net/davidcostadev/fwz0w722/